# Remove outer tags from Beautiful soup output

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have an xml which is generated after below beautifulsoup statement. It generates an XML which contains `html` and `body` tags. I want to remove both `html` and `body` tags from output. Can I please know how I can achieve the same ?

Code:

```
soup = bs(''.join(output), "lxml")
print("soup output : {}".format(soup.html))
```

output:

```
<html>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `print("soup output : {}".format(''.join(map(str, soup.body))))`

Comment: Nice, it works but I was thinking if there was a way from Beautifulsoup to handle it, because there will be str conversion in above ..

Comment: See @Sheng Zhuang's answer below. Looks like it might be better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
body = soup.find("body")
innerbody = body.decode_contents()
```